# Spring 3.0 + REST web service + json + xml

Tags: xml, json, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb

I have tried a lot of things now and looked up many places for this problem.

I am trying to use Spring MVC 3.0 to make a Rest web service call to get data in the form of JSON and XML. At the moment from what I have understood, when the jackson core and mapper jars are present in the classpath, Spring will automatically convert the response to jSon which is fine. This works as expected in the project.

What i am struggling with is to generate an xml response. I am not sure what I have to do for this. I have tried various ways to set the method to produce an xml response. As per my understanding jdk 6 and above have JAXB implementations. So when I annotate my POJO with XML annotations to produce XML, it should give me an XML response. But for some reason it keeps giving me JSON reponse. Any ideas? Following is my POJO which has the XMLRootElement jaxb annotation.

```
    package my.dto;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement(name = "mydto")
    public class MyDTO {

        String name;
        Long quantity;
        String type;


        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        @XmlElement
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
        @XmlElement
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }


        public Long getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }
        @XmlElement
        public void setQuantity(Long quantity) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        public MyDTO(String name, Long quantity) {
            this.name = name;
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        public MyDTO() {
            super();
        }

    }

**My Controller:**

package my.package;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import my.dto.MyDTO;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spring")
public class MyController {



    @RequestMapping(value="{b}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public @ResponseBody List<MyDTO> getMyList(@PathVariable String b) {


        MyDTO m1 = new MyDTO("My 1", Long.valueOf(100));
        MyDTO m2 = new MyDTO("My 2", Long.valueOf(200));

        List<MyDTO> list = new ArrayList<MyDTO>();
        list.add(m1);
        list.add(m2);

        return list;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One:**

**Yes**, you need the `@XML` annotations but they must be located in the **getters**, you have defined on the setters, that is wrong.

**Second**

You are returning a collection, for XML it is a little different, you need create the following

```
@XmlRootElement(name="list")
public class JaxbMyDTOList {

    private List<MyDTO> list;

    public JaxbMyDTOList(){}

    public JaxbMyDTOList(List<MyDTO> list){
        this.list=list;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="item")
    public List<MyDTO> getList(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Three:**

Change from:

```
@RequestMapping(value="{b}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Produces("application/xml")
public @ResponseBody List<MyDTO> getMyList(@PathVariable String b) {
```

To

```
@RequestMapping(value="{b}", 
                method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody JaxbMyDTOList getMyList(@PathVariable String b) {
```

Observe:

- `@Produces("application/xml")` removed and replaced by `produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)`
- `List<MyDTO>` replaced by `JaxbMyDTOList`

**Four:**

I suggest you create other `@RequestMapping` method, one for JSON and other to handle XML

Comment: When I removed and replaced @Produces("application/xml")  by produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE), there is an error code and it says "The attribute produces is undefined for the annotation type RequestMapping". Does Spring 3 have this property along with @RequestMapping? I actually tried this before as well and removed it later as i Was getting eclipse compile time error. Many thanks!

Comment: Guess what, that worked, i did not change the annotation for @RequestMapping  though as i was getting the error as stated in earlier comment. I think the problem was with the setters like you have rightly pointed out. One last thing for suggestion 4 where you have said to created 2 methods, one for JSON and one for XML. How can I invoke the correct method using the webservice url? If i have 2 methods, how to i call each from the http URL

Comment: Interesting about the `@RequestMapping` for the `produces` attribute for Spring 3. I am working with Spring 4 long time ago.. Explicitly what Spring 3 version you are using? I want check the API to confirm your problem

Comment: About XML and JSON, normally I use two urls for each `@RequestMapping`, for example `value="/{b}/xml"` and `value="/{b}/json"`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am using 3.0.6.RELEASE.jars for spring. I will try to see if i can invoke the different methods (JSON and XML) using two urls.

Comment: No problem, good to know all work fine… BTW, I have the checked the API, and yes, there is **no** `produces` attribute. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html